# How to preserve the color of input when piping to grep?

Tags: git, terminal, colors, grep, pipe

I would like to preserve the coloring of an arbitrary command (in my case and perhaps relevant to the question, `git diff`) when piping to `grep`, so that `grep` does not apply any additional coloring of its own and preserves the original.

For example, suppose the output of `git diff` contained

```
-    hello world
+    goodbye world
```

which would color the `-` line red and `+` line green. I would like the result of `git diff | grep world` to maintain the red and green coloring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
git diff --color=always | grep --color=never world
```

See [`git help diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---colorltwhengt).